# How should a chronological activity feed behave?

Tags: social-interfaces, social, activity-feed, chronology

I am developing an activity feed for a basic social app: you can follow people and people can follow you back.
When you follow someone, content from that person will appear on the activity feed.
I am debating wether the feed should show content posted by that person **before** I followed her, or if it should show content made only after I started following her.

I see that Twitter implements the first option, and Instagram the latter.

I can’t really understand the pros and cons of each. What are some good practices about this?

Comment: Please, could you give *a lot* more context?

Comment: @SteveDL I don't know what more context I can give without revealing what the app actually does, and i'm not allowed to do that until it's released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. If the app is about people that know each other (FB kind), then its a good idea to just limit the feed from the 'day they started following'. If its mostly strangers (Twitter kind), then you can have full feed visibility. Reason I say is, Person A could have said or written something about person B in the past and A might not like the idea of B knowing about A's past comments. It could be an idea or a controversial topic , not just what A said about B.. things like that. Like I said it depends what the relationship model is between users and what the 'following' model is - do users have control on who can follow them ?

EDIT:

I think sharing ALL feed sounds right. You need to have a very strong reason to shut down past feed .. Just my two cents.

Comment: At the momento the user has no control over who can follow them.

Comment: How about privacy concerns ? what type of feed are we talking about here ? I edited my answer.

Comment: the content shared by users is not actually sensitive, for example (not this case) cooking recipes. In the long run it's planned to allow a user to set his profile as private preventing other from following

Comment: Your contract can be terminated because of a tweet that you had two years ago. Barcelona B ex-player had this pain recently...

Comment: @Abektes true but i don't see that happening with the type of content users can share. But i'll give it some more thought. Tks for the warning.

Comment: @HugoAlves my pleasure, it is highly dependent on the context and content.